# How to set internal names of new SharePoint fields with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I'm trying to add a new field to a SharePoint list and set its internal name. I have both the static name and display name specified but I can't figure out why the internal name gets set as `First_x0020_Name`.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb 'https://server'
$list = $web.Lists['listName']
$newFieldXML = '<Field Type="Text" StaticName="FirstName" DisplayName="First Name"></Field>'
$list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($newFieldXML)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like [AddFieldAsXml cannot be used to set the internal name](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/420147)

According to the article, if you want to use AddFieldAsXml to set the internal name you need to:

> 1. Define your CAML so that the Internal Name you want to use is
>      actually set as the Display Name
> 2. Create the field with the call to AddFieldAsXml
> 3. After the field is created, retrieve it using the internal name and set the Title property to the real Display Name you wanted it to
>      be in the first place

You need two additional steps: retrieve the field and set the internal name

Comment: Adding the name attribute didn't work, the internal name is still being set based on the display name.

Answer (score 4):

This simply works for me-

XML should be of format:

```
$newFieldXML = '<Field Type="Text" Name="FirstName" StaticName="FirstName" DisplayName="First Name"></Field>'
```

In PowerShell use `[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAddFieldOptions]::AddFieldInternalNameHint` as third parameter of `AddFieldAsXml` function

```
$spListFields = $spList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($newFieldXML, $true, [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAddFieldOptions]::AddFieldInternalNameHint)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
$list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($newFieldXML, $true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPAddFieldOptions]::AddFieldInternalNameHint)
```

instead of

```
$list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($newFieldXML)
```

Refer [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spaddfieldoptions.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

**RESOLVED:**

Please check below post for the Answer:

[Set Field Internal Name For New Fields](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4343799a-67c4-47af-864f-f2b62eef651f/powershell-addfieldasxml-is-not-working-for-field-internal-name-is-this-a-bug-?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)

**Sample Code:**

Please use [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::**AddFieldInternalNameHint**

```
$fieldXml="<Field Type='Text' DisplayName='"+ $Field_DisplayName +"' 
Required='"+$Field_Required+"' MaxLength='255' 
StaticName='"+$Field_InternalName+"' Name='"+$Field_InternalName+"' />

$spoList.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldXml,$true,[Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.AddFieldOptions]::AddFieldInternalNameHint)

$spoList.Update()
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to create fields with internal name and then update the display name.

```
$web = Get-SPWeb 'https://server'
$list = $web.Lists['listName']
$newFieldXML = '<Field Type="Text" StaticName="FirstName" 
DisplayName="FirstName"></Field>'
$list.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($newFieldXML)
$fld = $list.Fields["FirstName"]
$fld.Title = "First Name"
$fld.Update();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't change the internalName of a field after his creation.
If you use XML to create field :
The internalName of field is set with the Attribute : "**Name**"

so your field XML defintion should be :

```
$newFieldXML = '<Field Type="Text" Name="FirstName" StaticName="FirstName" DisplayName="First Name"></Field>'
```